# how to implement Android ICS time picker on below version?

Tags: android, datetimepicker, timepicker

I want to implement ICS style Timepicker for all android devices?
Please provide me reference link for the same.

In case of creating a custom layout, how can i animate text like ICS timepicker?

Comment: Have you look at this link - https://github.com/ChristopheVersieux/HoloEverywhere

Answer (score -1):

check build version and set timePicker theme accordingly .

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder;
if (isICS()) {
         builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, AlertDialog.THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_DARK);
      } else {
         builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(CreateScheduleScreen.this);
      }

private boolean isICS() {
      int currentVer = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
      if (currentVer >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
         return true;
      }
      return false;
   }
```

//Build.VERSION.SDK_INT is available for 1.6+